# How to remove uninstalled game from list of steam tray

Tags: steam

I Uninstalling two games from my Steam, And in Steam application at *LIBRARY/GAMES* those don't listed, But when I right-click on Steam (icon) at my Windows tray those - uninstalled games - listed! and by clicking them installing page shows!
Is there any way to remove uninstalled games from steam tray right-click list?

I should add that I know those are my five recently played games, and I have just two games to play! I should also add this that my kid is playing with my PC so I don't want to click those old games from list of Steam tray icon!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please proofread and properly format your question.

Comment: Your question asks for I've thing, but you're asking for something else.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question for now, as it's asking two different questions and is symptomatic of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just play 5 different games and it'll pop off the list. The Steam tray icon lists your 5 most recently played games.

Edit: If you don't want your child from installing, why don't you enable [Family Mode](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=5149-EOPC-9918)? What's stopping him from opening the main interface and installing from there?

Comment: @shA.t That's an X-Y problem. If you want to prevent your kid from installing some games, you should ask about that.

Comment: @shA.t So you're fine with your kid installing games from places that are not the tray menu?

Comment: I enable Family Mode but those games are still shown! - But after re-login it works ;)

Comment: @shA.t You need to click the Red button at the top after activating to turn it on. It defaults to on whenever you re-login.